# Delegated factory function call - cannot find the proper syntax

Tags: c++, function-pointers, factory

I would like to pass a factory function pointer and variadic length arguments to a function but can't find the proper syntax. Something like this:

```
#include <memory>

struct Ressource {
    int a;
    float b;

    static std::shared_ptr<Ressource> make(int _a, float _b) {
        return std::shared_ptr<Ressource>(new Ressource(_a, _b));
    }

private:
    Ressource(int _a, float _b) : a{ _a }, b{ _b } {}
};

template<typename R, typename... Args>
void delegate_(std::shared_ptr<R>(R::*factory)(Args...), Args... args) {
    std::shared_ptr<R> ressource = factory(args...);
}

void test() {
    delegate_(&Ressource::make, 1, 3.0f);
}
```

I get (msvc) : error C2064: [error follows in french :]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factory method `make` should be a static member of `Resource`.  Then `delegate_` would take just a pointer to a function, rather than a pointer to a member function, and it would then be able to call the factory function.  The problem with your current implementation is that in order to call `factory` from within `delegate_`, you need to provide a `Resource` object to call it on.

Comment: Stupid me, of course "make" is static, I managed to fail at writing my example lol. Thanks tho - I could fix my code.